# Need to include .ocx and .tlb files in VB6 package

Tags: vb6, ocx, typelib

Suppose, I'm using many `.ocx` and `.tlb` files in my VB6 program that are not provided by Windows. Now, If I want to run my program in a PC where these files are not present, should I have to install and register both these types of file to be able to run my program or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to distribute the OCX files. However, you probably don't need to distribute TLB files, unless you are using remote COM or passing a User Defined Type from that TLB file via a Variant parameter.

Comment: Any way to determine this. I'm using NTVBSvcW.tlb which might be using NTVBSvcW.odl and WINTYPE1.ODL

Comment: @user2265784 Any way to determine what? Also, explain the second sentence.

Comment: How can I determine if NTVBSvcW.tlb, NTVBSvcW.odl and WINTYPE1.ODL need distribution or not.

Comment: @user2265784 For TLB: If you are using remote automation with that type, then you must distribute it. Are you using Remove Automation? If you pass a UDT via a Variant parameter, you must distribute this. Are you passing a UDT from that TLB via a Variant parameter? For ODL: These are source code files! The TLB file only has a dependency on them because you compile them to create the TLB file.

Comment: If only your programs will be using those TLBs then you don't need to distribute them.  The type information in them has already been used by the compiler and you're done with it.  A binary distribution only needs your EXE and the OCXs and DLLs that it uses.  DCOM might be an exception, but only if you are creating an ActiveX EXE.

Comment: @Bob77 Not just DCOM. As I've said previously, if you reference a TLB, and then pass a struct/UDT declared in that TLB via a Variant, COM needs the TLB to be registered and present to be able to make sense of the underlying UDT.